# Hide menu in Xamarin when tapping on current page link

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation, master-detail

I created an empty Master-Detail project in Xamarin. When I tap the About link from the menu it navigates me to the About page and hides the menu. However if I tap the About link again nothing happens. I would like for it to hide the menu. How can I accomplish this?

[Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLDML.png)

Main Page -

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        Dictionary<int, NavigationPage> MenuPages = new Dictionary<int, NavigationPage>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

            MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Browse, (NavigationPage)Detail);
        }

        public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
        {
            if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                switch (id)
                {
                    case (int)MenuItemType.Browse:
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage()));
                        break;
                    case (int)MenuItemType.About:
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()));
                        break;
                }
            }

            var newPage = MenuPages[id];

            if (newPage != null && Detail != newPage)
            {
                Detail = newPage;

                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                    await Task.Delay(100);

                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Menu Page -

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
        List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
            {
                new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Browse, Title="Browse" },
                new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About" }
            };

            ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

            ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];
            ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                    return;

                var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
                await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: set `MainPage's IsPresented = false;`

Comment: @Jason But it's already doing that in the NavigateFromMenu method. If I set the IsPresented property to false in MainPage.xaml it just has the same behavior.

Comment: if you navigate to the page that you are already on, it is not executing the code in the IF statement.  You need to move that line outside of the IF

Comment: @Jason I moved it out of the if statement but nothing happens. The NavigateFromMenu method doesn't fire at all. And the ListViewMenu ItemSelected event in the Menu page doesn't fire.

Comment: try using ItemTapped instead of ItemSelected, OR set the `SelectedItem = null` inside of `ItemSelected`